# jquery val() change automatically from number to undefined in the time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have got an "input" that is driving me crazy.
the input is "echoed" from a PHP function into an HTML page.

```
    '<td class="product-quantity" data-title="Quantity">
                            <div class="quantity">
                <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5ed41a96cc5c6">Casual shirt quantity</label>
        <input
            type="number"
            id="input'.$e.'"
            class="qtychg input-text qty text"
            step="0.5"
            value="'.$arr[$e]['quantity'].'"
            size="4"
            inputmode="numeric" />
                <span class="product-qty-arrows">
            <span id="'.$e.'" class="product-qty-increase lnr lnr-chevron-up"></span>
            <span id="'.$e.'" class="product-qty-decrease lnr lnr-chevron-down"></span>
        </span>
        </div>
                            </td>'
```

I can increase/decrease the input' value  using the span "class="product-qty-increase" that call the following javascript script:

```
<script>
$('span').click(function (){

var Id=$(this).attr('id');
var val=$('#input'+Id).val();
var className= this.className;

if(className == "product-qty-increase lnr lnr-chevron-up"){

    val++;

}else if(className == "product-qty-decrease lnr lnr-chevron-down"){

    val--;
}

alert(val);

 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "actions.php?action=chgQty",
                        data: "key=" + Id +"&val=" + val ,
                        success: function(result) { 
                          location.reload();
                        }
                     })


});
</script>
```

THE PROBLEMs that are driving me crazy are 2:

1) the "alert(val);" pop up twice !!!! one with the correct number and the second time with "undefined"

[image]
[image]

2) obviously I can't send the $.ajax call because the value is turning into undefined.

Any idea???

Comment: You shouldn't use the same ID for multiple elements.

Comment: Instead of checking the entire `className` variable, use `if ($(this).hasClass("product-qty-increase")`

Comment: select class `$('.lnr ')` instead of `span`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have nested spans, and you're binding the event handler to all of them. When you click on the up or down spans, the event bubbles out to `<span class="product-qty-arrows">` and fires there as well.

Use a more specific selector so you only bind to the up and down buttons.

```js
$('span.lnr').click(function() {

  var Id = $(this).attr('id');
  var val = $('#input' + Id).val();

  if ($(this).hasClass("product-qty-increase")) {
    val++;
  } else if ($(this).hasClass("product-qty-decrease")) {
    val--;
  }

  alert(val);

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "actions.php?action=chgQty",
    data: {key: Id, val: val},
    success: function(result) {
      location.reload();
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks!!!!! It worked !!!! I was becoming crazy....

Comment: add `if( val !== undefined)` before calling the `$.ajax`,

Comment: @EhsanNazeri The value of an input can never be undefined, it's always a string. That would only happen if the input doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi EhsanNazeri, as Barmar said,  I was "  binding the event handler to all of them" so I got the first value coming from the span I clicked and the second ( undefined) from the one that I didn't click